# A very strange rhyme

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I wish I understood, 
but you have closed your mind,
they seem so hard to find,
it used to be so good.

You're in the mood,
when you get the chance,
for a dance,
You're in the mood.

Buy some Chinese food, to go.
have your dinner watching TV,
a single episode of Dallas that I didn't see,
at eight o'clock or so

**Who am I looking for?**

Comment: Too many rhymes, my left eyeball imploded

Comment: ABBA (the rhyming scheme)? Somehow I haven't gotten used to that.

Comment: @JoeZ. Oke i'm going to delete this in a few mins, it were all sentences from abba, and yes i tried to make the rhyming scheme resemble ABBA but i failed desperatly. maybe i'll try to do it better a next time, this one was just ridiciousl and easy :P

Comment: Wow, that was actually the _answer_? Didn't expect that. :P

Comment: @JoeZ. see how bad it was xD

Comment: I wasn't even trying to phrase it as a guess, it was more intended to be like "You're using ABBA?"

Comment: What are the first and third verses, by the way? I know the second one is Dancing Queen.

Comment: (Also, your rhymes were fine, just your meter was horrendous. :P)

Comment: First one S.O.S. and 3th one The Day Before You Came

Comment: what do you meen with meter?

Comment: @JoeZ. Nice, you've ruined a riddle! Ahahahahah!

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat: OH, that's right, the first one is SOS. Can't believe I forgot that, I _have_ the *Mamma Mia* soundtrack at home.

Comment: @leoll2 I didn't mean to! :<

Comment: Right eyeball imploded

Comment: @Vincent: I believe when he said "meter", he meant "cadence" or "rhythm". Rhyming is one thing, but if it doesn't follow a syllabic pattern, it just feels clumsy and forced.

Comment: @JoeZ. You or Vincent should post an answer.  Without checking the song lyrics, seems like a decent riddle.

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes it was extremely forced, i will do better next time, i'm going to make a good one you wait and see :P but in the mean time i'll sitck with crypto riddles.

Comment: @JoeZ. ye post an answer, i'll leave the question and i will (hopefully soon) post a better one.

Comment: @Spacemonkey how does that even work? Hahahah xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> ABBA. 
>
> All the verses are taken from lyrics of ABBA songs, and each verse follows an ABBA rhyming scheme.